# Intrinsic definition of divergence and curl

Tags: vector-analysis

Are the intrinsic definitions of divergence and curl the theorems of Green-Ostrogradski and Stokes-Ampere respectively ?

What is a rigorous derivation of their expression in a coordinate system ?

Comment: Have you seen the limit-integral definitions?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Well [look here](http://mathinsight.org/curl_definition_line_integral) for the definition of curl.  If that's what you're looking for, you might want to find a copy of Schey's *Div, Grad, Curl, and All That* -- he does of good job of explaining the limit-integral definitions.  BTW, you can also define the [exterior derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593920/integral-definition-of-exterior-derivative) this way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know these theorems. However, you can define div grad curl using the Riemannian metric's pairing, the hodge * operator, and the exterior derivative. Let $T_1$ denote the map from one-forms to vector fields induced by the pairing.

$T_1 df$ is the gradient.

$T_1 * d T_{1}^{-1}v$ is the curl.

$*d*T_{1}^{-1}v$ is the divergence.

Comment: This is beyond my current math knowledge (I'm a physics undergraduate student) but thanks anyway.